# Python Selenium login without using id tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to try and auto login. The driver has methods for id but which method do I use if the html page does not have id?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter ID here (Example - someuser)" name="LoginID" required="">
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password here" name="Password" required="">
<button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Currently I have this but I need to replace the id method of course just not sure to what

```
def login(url):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("text").send_keys("MyuserName")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("somepassword")
    driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

login(url)
```

Comment: You can use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` method which pretty much enables you to query elements like you can do with JS in the browser with `document.querySelector`. More about CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Comment: You are correct I used     driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=text]").send_keys("someuser")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=password]").send_keys("somepass")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
gribvirus74 do you want to post answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods have been deprecated:

```
warnings.warn(
        "find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead",
        DeprecationWarning,
        stacklevel=2,
    )
```

You may use the following:

```
find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None)
```

The possible search locator are as follow:

```
class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

For your code try the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
search_container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="LoginID"]')
```